# Prestashop - How to add or remove space between footer and page content

Tags: css, prestashop, footer, space

I would like to ask you some help about managing the space between the footer and the page content in Prestashop.

My Prestashop version is 1.6.1.17.

The website is [www.backlabel.com](http://www.backlabel.com).

I have the following problem:

- On the home page, the space between the embedded video and the footer is greater that I want to be and  would like to reduce it. However I cannot identify, even through the Inspect Function of Chrome browser, the part that I should modify and I'm lost.
- I know that in asylum.css there is a #footer part that has some specifications, however I already have removed its margin, and that space still remains. See image below for more clarification.
  [Distance between embedded video and footer highlighted in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU5Yu.jpg)
- On the [login page](https://www.backlabel.com/login?back=my-account), having removed the margin from the footer, subsequentially it remains very attached to the content while instead I would like to add a space and to make the footer stay on the bottom. See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMhGY.jpg) for more clarification.

Can anyone help?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the space on between your video and the footer, this css code will solve your issue :

```
body .cms_24 .wht_bg{
  top:0;
}
```

For your 3rd point (login page), use this JS code to keep your footer always at the bottom. Tested and works great.

```
var docHeight = $(window).height();
var footerHeight = $('#footer').height();
var footerTop = $('#footer').position().top + footerHeight;
if (footerTop < docHeight)
    $('#footer').css('margin-top', (docHeight - footerTop) + 'px');
```

cheers :)